# Sistema de Amigos com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Olá, gostaria de saber como criar um sistema de amizades para minha aplicação, estilo facebook. Não estou fazendo uma rede social, mas preciso implementar esse sistema.

Tenho uma tabela de usuários em que armazeno dados como id e username das pessoas cadastradas.

Vi algumas soluções por ai, que diziam para criar uma tabela "amigos", e nessa tabela gravar o id do solicitante, e o id do solicitado, dai quando o usuário fizesse login, o sistema carregaria os amigos dele a partir desta tabela. Mas em termos performáticos, no caso da aplicação ficar muito grande, essa solução me parece pouco viável. Ia demorar um bom tempo para carregar os amigos de um determinado usuário, se a tabela tivesse, por exemplo, 50 mil registros.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer para criar esse sistema, de uma maneira eficiente?

Comment: Então cara, quero uma coisa diferente do que está nessa pergunta, lá ele usou uma tabela de amigos, quero um jeito de criar esse sistema sem ter que criar uma tabela enorme, no caso "amigos", para armazenar a informação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma que você citou é a mais eficiente utilizando um banco de dados relacional. Se você tiver problemas em fazer a escalabilidade do banco de dados, contrate um serviço que faça isso por você de forma automatizada. Um muito usado e que eu recomendo é o [RDS da Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/rds/).

O próprio facebook utiliza um modelo não relacional para fazer esse tipo de transação de dados, se lhe convir, pesquise também sobre [MongoDB](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) e veja se ele atende bem suas necessiades. A curva de aprendizagem é pequena, e você pode implementá-lo em apenas uma parte do seu sistema (no seu caso, as interações entre usuários).